# How can I install faiss-gpu?

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, faiss

I ran into this problem when trying to install faiss-gpu
pip install faiss-gpu
This is the error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement faiss-gpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for faiss-gpu
My GPU is NVIDIA RTX 3050Ti

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   Driver Version: 537.13       CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     TCC/WDDM  | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 ...  WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P0              13W /  60W |      0MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I had unistalled the faiss-cpu before I installed the faiss-gpu.
Maybe my CUDA's version is not compatible with faiss-gpu?
I try to find some documents but it doesn't really help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that your CUDA version is not compatible. According to their [install readme](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/b77061ff5eb2d5dc3b1fc25b240578c2d686a646/INSTALL.md), faiss-gpu is available for CUDA 11.4 and 12.1.